# Put all libraries (bootstrap....) in one file at the end of development

Tags: css

One of my coworkers puts all the css files in o one lib.css in the end of the project. I hate it because when i need to change something its just bad the see which scribt is involved (i see its in lib.css put not if its bootstrap or whatever).

I think this makes everything more complicated or is this the "right" way?

Comment: "avoid asking subjective questions where … your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?” ([help/dont-ask])

Answer (score 1):

The "right" way is subjective.

A single lib.css file done right (minified, optimized, etc) normally allows for quicker downloads for the visitor.

Quite often, on the development side there are multiple css files (or scss or less) that are combined for production deployment.  This allows for easier debugging in a non-production environment (smaller single purpose files) while providing the benefits of quicker downloads in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

So, as Adam points out, the 'right' way would be to at least include the original files your coworker used to generate the lib.css file from. If he/she includes a build configuration with that (using grunt/gulp/webpack...), it would be even better.

Handing over a single compressed optimized js or css file only would not be very 'polite'. Politeness is also subjective.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's better to write css cache system which will get all css scripts and put it into one, deleting spaces and enters by the way. There is something more confusing for developers as editing one, very long file?